# How to make this multiple conditional if else block into shorter syntax - javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have written a conditional block by using multiple if  else-if statements. I have checked in various articles to avoid of using multiple if else. So, how to use enums for this multiple if-else conditions?

**Here is the code:**

```
if (!props.focusable) {
    svg = svg.replace("<svg ", '<svg focusable="false" ');
  }
  options.domProps = { innerHTML: svg };
} else {
  options.class.push("fa-" + iconName);
  if (props.brand) {
    options.class.push("fab");
  } else if (props.fab) {
    options.class.push("fab");
  } else if (props.regular) {
    options.class.push("far");
  } else if (props.far) {
    options.class.push("far");
  } else if (props.light) {
    options.class.push("fal");
  }  else if (props.fal) {
    options.class.push("fal");
  } else if (props.old) {
    options.class.push("fa");
  }  else if (props.fa) {
    options.class.push("fa");
  }  else {
    options.class.push("fas");
  }
}
```

How to make it shorter and better in performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a table-driven approach that can support any number of comparisons without adding more lines of code (just another line to the table):

```
const tags = [
    "brand", "fab",
    "regular", "far",
    "light", "fal",
    "old", "fa"
];

if (!props.focusable) {
    svg = svg.replace("<svg ", '<svg focusable="false" ');
    options.domProps = { innerHTML: svg };
} else {
    options.class.push("fa-" + iconName);
    let cls = "fas";
    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i += 2) {
        if (props[tags[i]] || props[tags[i + 1]]) {
            cls = tags[i + 1];
            break;
        }
    }
    options.class.push(cls);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine certain `else-if`'s using `OR` operator:

```
if (!props.focusable) {
    svg = svg.replace("<svg ", '<svg focusable="false" ');
  }
  options.domProps = { innerHTML: svg };
} else {
  options.class.push("fa-" + iconName);
  if (props.brand || props.fab) {
    options.class.push("fab");
  } else if (props.regular || props.far) {
    options.class.push("far");
  } else if (props.light || props.fal) {
    options.class.push("fal");
  } else if (props.old || props.fa) {
    options.class.push("fa");
  } else {
    options.class.push("fas");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
options.class.push("fa-" + iconName)
props.brands || props.fab ? options.class.push("fab") :
props.regular || props.far ? options.class.push("far") :
props.light || props.fal ? options.class.push("fal") :
props.old || props.fa ? options.class.push("fa") :
options.class.push("fas")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!props.focusable) {
    svg = svg.replace("<svg ", '<svg focusable="false" ');
  }
  options.domProps = { innerHTML: svg };
} else {
  options.class.push("fa-" + iconName);

  let cls = "fas";
  if (props.brand || props.fab) cls = "fab";
  if (props.regular || props.far) cls  = "far"; 
  if (props.light || props.fal) cls  = "fal"; 
  if (props.old || props.fa) cls  = "fa";

  options.class.push(cls);
}
```

Hope this help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

yo can use switch statement .switch case use for multiple statement.
read this for your referrence
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).